# ¿Cuál es la mejor manera de guardar un avatar en MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, imagen, spring-boot

estoy haciendo una aplicación para el móvil y necesito guardar en MongoDB los avatares de mis usuarios. El JSON que tengo en mente guardar es el siguiente:

```
{
  "nombre": "",
  "alias": "",
  "email": "",
  "avatar": "",
  "pass": ""
}
```

Me gustaría saber cual es la manera más optima para guardar el avatar en la base de datos. Hay que tener en cuenta que puedo tener muchos usuarios por lo que la carga de muchos usuarios debería lo más rápida posible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tengo entendido que la aproximación más conveniente seria
guardarlos codificados en un String **Base64**.

Se trata de una codificación conocida que tendrás procesar para codificar y descodificar, es útil pero recuerda tener en cuenta el límite de los documentos de MongoDB (16MB). Creo que con esta forma aumenta el tamaño que ocupan aproximadamente un 33%.

La aproximación que te recomendaría es guardar el fichero en un servidor y acceder a el mediante un endpoint, teniendo que así almacenar en MongoDB únicamente la dirección donde se ubica.

Es importante también considerar el formato con el que guardaras las imagenes, pues extensiones como .jpeg vendrán comprimidas y tardaran menos en la transmisión de datos.